# Custom tab in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, actionbarsherlock, android-custom-view

I am an Android beginner and I am in the learning process. I am creating an application for which I would like to customize my Tabs in actionbar to something like the one in the Path app. I am not able to figure out how they achieved it. I disabled home and the title in the actionbar. I guess i have to inflate a custom view with the tabs and somehow relate it to my viewpager. But I am clueless on how! I ve attached the image of the path apps action bar. I would like to achieve the same effect. Any help will be appreciated. Thanking you in advance.

[the path app actionbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TwSC.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Create a full-screen layout-file.

The following example/tutorial shows you to create individual tabs

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Comment: But in the path app what they have is the native actionbar. They have somehow modified the way tabs appear. Creating a full screen layout will mean that I design the whole actionbar itself. Is that the only way to do it?